# Autocomplete for cells in dataGridView from dataset using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, autocomplete

I have a dataGridView that is populated from a dataset:

```
  dataGridView1.DataSource = aSH_ORDER_DBDataSet.ASH_PROD_ORDERS;
```

When adding new entries to the datagridview is it possible to have the cells Autocomplete or suggest based on the content of other cells in that column?

I have searched for this, but everything I found is for textboxes and it doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figured it out.

This is partly grabbed from somewhere else and edited by me for my specific use:

This code grabs the data from the current column you are editing, and will suggest Autocomplete answers based on that column.

```
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
            TextBox autoText = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (autoText != null)
            {
                autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                autoText.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                AutoCompleteStringCollection DataCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                addItems(DataCollection);
                autoText.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection;
            }
    }

    public void addItems(AutoCompleteStringCollection col)
    {
        var selectedColumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

        List<string> headerList = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow row in aSH_ORDER_DBDataSet.ASH_PROD_ORDERS.Rows)
        {
            headerList.Add(row[selectedColumn].ToString());
        }

        List<string> cleanHeaderList = headerList.Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (var item in cleanHeaderList)
        {
            col.Add(item);
        }
    }
```